# escrever no html frases do json

Tags: javascript, json

Eu tentei fazer uma mini base de dados em JSON:

```
[
    {
        "titulo": "Exemplo",
        "localizacao": "Rua de Exemplo",
        "texto": "Texto grande de exemplo para usar como teste"
    }
]
```

Depois criei uma variável geral para o JSON para poder utilizar o JSON num ficheiro a parte:

```
function LoadJsonData() {

    var jsondata;

    $.ajax({
      url: './Json/JsonSite.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function (json) {
        jsondata = json;
      }
    });

    return jsondata;
  }
```

mas estou com um problema.

Eu queria escrever o título que tá no JSON, a localização e o texto no meu HTML, mas não tá a escrever.

```
var json = LoadJsonData();

document.getElementById("tituloareas").innerHTML = json[1].titulo;

document.getElementById("localizacaoareas").innerHTML = json[1].localizacao;

document.getElementById("textoareas").innerHTML = json[1].texto;
```

```
<div class="informacaodasareas">
    <h2 class="tituloinfo" id="tituloareas"></h2>

    <p class="localizacaoinfo" id="localizacaoareas"></p>

    <h5 class="textoinfo" id="textoareas"></h5> 

    <div class="imageminfo" id="imagemareas"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: json[1]? não seria json[0]?

Comment: @RicardoPontual mudei para json[0] e nada mudou

Comment: depois dessa linha `var json = LoadJsonData();` pode mostrar o conteúdo que retornou na variável json?

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu coloquei tudo eu criei a var json e defeni que seria igual a função que esta noutro ficheiro! tas a perceber esse é o meu script eu acho que esta faltando algo para ativar os document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você alterar a sua função `LoadJsonData` para receber um callback, você consegue fazer isso. Veja:

```js
function LoadJsonData(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: './Json/JsonSite.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            if (callback) callback(json)
        }
    });
}

// Setar os dados via callback
LoadJsonData(function (json) {
    $("#tituloareas").text(json[0].titulo);
    $("#localizacaoareas").text(json[0].localizacao);
    $("#textoareas").text(json[0].texto);
});
```

Comment: Mas eu gostava de ter um json num ficheiro a parte e em outro ficheiro queria criar uma variavel que basicamente ao usar essa var ja conectava o json no javascript assim era mais facil ate para me organizar para caso o json seja muito grande nao fique um javascript gigante

Comment: Dessa forma que exemplifiquei o arquivo `.json` continuará dentro do seu próprio ficheiro.

Comment: e a var é geral? caso eu queria usar a função em outro script ou depois tenho de repetir o comando (curiosidade)

Comment: Você pode usar essa função em outras páginas sem problemas

Comment: Ok obrigado vou tentar inserir no meu codigo para ver se funciona então!

Answer (score 3):

Eu fiz um exemplo com os dados **mockados** e como pode perceber funcionou, claro que tive que trocar o **`[1]`** por **`[0]`** do contrário não funcionaria tbm. Provavelmente seu problema é na requisição **Ajax**. Para você certificar-se que o problema é na requisição de um console.log(json) dentro de **`success`** e observe o que é retornado e se é no formato esperado.

```js
let json = LoadJsonData();

function LoadJsonData() {

  let dados = [{
    "titulo": "Exemplo",
    "localizacao": "Rua de Exemplo",
    "texto": "Texto grande de exemplo para usar como teste"
  }];

  return dados;
}

document.getElementById("tituloareas").innerHTML = json[0].titulo;

document.getElementById("localizacaoareas").innerHTML = json[0].localizacao;

document.getElementById("textoareas").innerHTML = json[0].texto;
```

```html
<div class="informacaodasareas">

  <h2 class="tituloinfo" id="tituloareas"></h2>

  <p class="localizacaoinfo" id="localizacaoareas"></p>

  <h5 class="textoinfo" id="textoareas"></h5>

  <div class="imageminfo" id="imagemareas"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Mas eu gostava de ter um json num ficheiro a parte e em outro ficheiro queria criar uma variavel que basicamente ao usar essa var ja conectava o json no javascript assim era mais facil ate para me organizar para caso o json seja muito grande nao fique um javascript gigante

Comment: @DavidMv, então você pode simplesmente declarar a variável global em um arquivo js separado.

Comment: Foi o que tentei fazer infelizmente não funcionou

Comment: Sim, eu só criei o exemplo mockado para ver que o problema é no retorno da requisição Ajax!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function loadJsonData() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: './Json/JsonSite.json',
    dataType: 'json',
  );
}

loadJsonData().then(function (data) {
  document.getElementById("tituloareas").textContent = data[0].titulo;
  document.getElementById("localizacaoareas").textContent = data[0].localizacao;
  document.getElementById("textoareas").textContent = data[0].texto;
})
```

Comment: Mas eu gostava de ter um json num ficheiro a parte e em outro ficheiro queria criar uma variavel que basicamente ao usar essa var ja conectava o json no javascript assim era mais facil ate para me organizar para caso o json seja muito grande nao fique um javascript gigante